# Seifer's Scar And Related Plot Points?

Tags: final-fantasy-8

In Final Fantasy 8, the nurse and Quistis make a big deal about Squall getting his face cut during the [opening sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pZ2ibvZb2Q&feature=player_detailpage#t=166) wherein he is having a training session with Seifer. Why do they not make a big deal about Squall returning the favor and giving Seifer a similar scar?

Also, why does Seifer not have a similar bandage, lest he have blood spewing everywhere, and why do they not yell at Squall for returning the blow?

Comment: Seifer initiated, what are you taking about?

Comment: I should add that this opening sequence is the best I've ever seen for any video game ever.

Comment: @Ender He did, but they never mention the scar(Seifer's) in game

Comment: "Why do they not yell at Squall for doing the exact same thing, except initiating?" implies that Squall initiated, I'm not sure what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Ender He did the exact same thing, except initiate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That battle in the opening was the result of Seifer taunting Squall on for a fight. at the start of the game Quistis does scold Squall for falling for it and in class she reminds the students (i assume sarcastically) to

> try and not kill your partner during practice

given that she seems to imply that it's normal for students to spar and there's no restrictions unlike the Training Sector of the Garden (younger students must be with an instructor) it's probably normal but they don't use weapons which can kill (or maybe Junction certain Para-Magic which prevents injury and death which Seifer and Squall did not do) unless an Instructor is around.

given Seifer's "bad boy" image he probably sees the scar as a badge on honor and probably is proud of it. given the one he gave Squall he probably thinks his smaller scar is proof he was the victor in the fight.

As for why Squall even fell for Seifer's taunts, when your walking down the corridor from the Infirmary the choices you have to reply to Quistis both imply Squall was trying to maintain his reputation, one option just have him remain silent (like he always does) while the other he says he couldn't let Seifer get away with it, since we never see that scene i've assumed it went something like this

> Seifer: Tonight, you and me and this time for real, no kiddie Para-Magic as a safe guard and no Instructor Trepe to get in our way
>
> Squall: go by yourself, i have better things to do
>
> Raijin: you think your so tough blowing off the boss like that ya know
>
> Fuujin: CHICKEN
>
> Seifer: Fuujin, Raijin, leave it, it's not his fault he's pathetic, it just showns he's not fit to be SeeD
>
> Squall:......what time

obviously i'm assuming that Fuujin and Raijin was there as they probably got the other instructors involved after Squall's Counter Attack, looking out for Seifer as they always do